# listBox is not displaying manual string inside it, but displaying the 'str' value

Tags: c#, listbox

Firstly What the hell is that, I think there is no any expression for it but I am asking you specialists:

```
string onUserName = msj.Substring(3);
lstMsjClient.Items.Add(onUserName + "is online now.");
```

Here the `onUserName` can be displayed inside the `lstMsjClient` but the "is online now" can not be displayed inside the `lstMsjClient`. 
So is not that funny, what is the reason ?
That's soooo interesting.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Does this code only show *part* of the string on the UI? Is that what you're saying? Try using `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` prior to / after adding you items to the `ListBox`, if you're adding multiple. Also, unless your `Substring(3)` includes a space on the end, you're probably going to want a space at the beginning of your `"is online now."` message.

Comment: Unable to replicate the indicated behaviour. Please post an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as your current code works as expected.

Comment: Does your Listbox has a width value that is simply to small?

Comment: the listBox displaying the value called 'onUserName' but after '+' the listBox doesn't displaying the 'is online now'. that's realy interesting cuz in another all my progs the listBox displaying all the string inside it. But in that prog listBox doesn't displaying. That' sooo weird.

Comment: And also my listBox has no any width or height everthing is default. I am gonna be crazy is that a bug of microsoft ? and yes brian tompsett yes this on the listBox on the UI the string is just like that for as onUserName = "Brain" the code seems on the screen like that just Brain not more, where is "is online now" ????????

Comment: Replicate the issue inside a small sample application (MCV), then you can start thinking about it being a bug. What is `msj`? If it is a custom class, what does `Substring(3)` do? All of the questions asked will be easily answered with an MCV.

Comment: the msj is a string like that ~n~username  and substring takes the username and if that's a bug of VS 2011 or c# compiler i will be very angry because i am making a big project and if c# leave me along . . . . by the way im so glad you for helping me

Comment: Please provide an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use

```
string msj = "One";
string onUserName = msj.Substring(3);
lstMsjClient.Items.Add(onUserName + "is online now.");

//O is 0
//n is 1
//e is 2
//after blank 3. index


Output : "is online now."
```

because Substring(3) mean index start 3.

if you want first 3 chars you must use Substring(0,3)

try this code

```
string msj = "OneTwoThree";
string onUserName = msj.Substring(3);
listBox1.Items.Add(onUserName + "is online now.");

Output : "TwoThreeis online now." ok?
```

Comment: no I solved that the problem because of apı and SOLVED